# ¿Qué es "inventar el hilo negro"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, méxico, expresiones

Una expresión muy común en México es "inventar el hilo negro". ¿Qué significa?

Ejemplo:

> No hay que inventar el hilo negro.

Comment: FYI: Never heard it here (Argentina)

Comment: Expresión desconocida en España, donde se dice "inventar la pólvora".

Comment: En Cuba se dice inventar el agua tibia.

Comment: Nunca la he oído en Colombia. Aquí también se habla de inventar/descubrir el agua tibia.

Comment: "Reinvent the wheel" is the closest english equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo más simple es:

> *No trabajes en cosas o ideas que ya están hechas o pensadas con anterioridad, que son un hecho y/o han sido probadas con resultados exitosos.*

Answer (score 7):

Yo soy de México, y en mi experiencia, es más común la frase "**descubrir** el hilo negro". Y se dice que alguien "descubrió el hilo negro" cuando esa persona alardea o presume de haber descubierto algo que carece de dificultad para ser encontrado, algo que realmente es muy obvio o salta a la vista.

Si tuviéramos varios hilos de colores, obviamente seria bastante "fácil" encontrar el negro, porque "resalta", de aquí viene la frase.

Pero supongo que si hablamos específicamente de "**inventar** el hilo negro" lleve el mismo significado, ya que erróneamente a veces se dice que alguien "inventó" algo, cuando en realidad lo que hizo fue "descubrir" algo.

Comment: En España solemos decir "descubrir la sopa de ajo", probablemente sea lo mismo.

Comment: En Colombia dicen "Descubrir el agua tibia" o "Descrubrir que el agua moja"

Comment: Otra expresión que he oído yo en España es *Descubrir el Mediterráneo* (lo cual tiene bastante sentido para un español, porque descubrir el mar que rodea casi el 90% del territorio es bastante... absurdo) **:D**

Comment: puede ser el atlantico !

Answer (score 3):

"Descubrir el hilo negro" viene de cuando algunos ilusionistas hacían que una pelotita rodara de una mano a la otra desafiando la fuerza de gravedad. El espectador percibía que la pelotita estaba suspendida "mágicamente" en el aire, hasta que descubrían el truco: un par de hilos negros por los que dicha pelotita pasaba de mano a mano.

"Inventar el hilo negro", por el otro lado, tiene el mismo origen, pero se refiere a las múltiples maneras en que una persona (que no conoce el truco del hilo negro) trataría de enteder cómo una pelotita se mueve horizontalmente sin caer al suelo. Por extensión, se emplea cuando alguien busca soluciones complejas a problemas que ya han sido solucionados de maneras más simples.

Comment: ¡Interesante! ¿Podrías indicar fuentes de todo esto, si las tienes? Bienvenido a [spanish.se] y hasta pronto :)

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente lo que se acostumbra es decir:

> No hay que inventar/descubrir el hilo negro.

Lo que significa es que no es necesario hacer algo novedoso o complicado para resolver un problema puesto que ya existen soluciones conocidas y que se sabe que funcionan que se pueden aplicar al mismo.

De hecho es exactamente el mismo significado que tiene la frase en Inglés que Tom Au menciona en su respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Estas son las otras formas de decir lo mismo en otras regiones que se han mencionado en las otras respuestas y comentarios. ¡Edita e incluye la utilizada en tu país!

---

En general, se usa en todos los países la expresión:

> Reinventar la rueda

Además, por países:

España

> - Inventar la pólvora
>
> - Descubrir la sopa de ajo

Colombia

> - Inventar el agua tibia
>
> - Descubrir que el agua moja

Cuba

> Inventar el agua tibia

México

> Descubrir el hilo negro

--
Además, esta es la expresión en otros idiomas:

Inglés

> reinvent the wheel
>
> <sub>reinventar la rueda</sub>

Francés

> <del>inventer le fil à couper le beurre</del> réinventer la roue
>
> <sub><del>descubrir el hilo de mantequilla</del> reinventar la rueda</sub>

Comment: Añado esta referencia de acuerdo con lo indicado en [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674).

Comment: A juzgar por la respuesta de @Dante, diria que reinventar la rueda no es lo mismo que descubrir el hilo negro, ya que reinventar la rueda simplemente significa dedicarle tiempo a algo inventar algo que ya se ha hecho mil veces, independientemente de lo sencillo o complicado que sea, mientras que descubrir el hilo negro sería mas el nivel absurdo como descubrir que el agua moja.

Answer (score 0):

The English equivalent would be "don't reinvent the wheel." According to a comment below, it would be "Reinventar la rueda" tambien en español.

Comment: Yes, but he's asking about the meaning in Spanish, not equivalences in other languages.

Comment: OK, maybe this doesn't answer the exact question of the OP. But it could answer the questions of OTHERS with similar (but not the same) concerns.

Comment: I agree with Tom.  This could help some people understand what the phrase means, which is the question.

Comment: "Reinventar la rueda" es también de uso común en español.